# Is possible see the "WDIO Configuration" added in a project already build?

Tags: wdio

Is possible to see the "WDIO Configuration" added to a project already built?

I mean, as we can see in the picture added, I wanna see the list of configurations added but in a project that is already built... exist a specific command in WDIO to do that?

More context:
My main objective is to know the configuration of the following line
Here the image link
https://ibb.co/Jqn75N7

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

The place where you can see all the different configurations selected at the begining is `wdio.conf.js` or `wdio.conf.ts`

Based on the [wdio](https://webdriver.io/docs/typescript/#configuration) documentation, if you want to use TypeScript:

> You will need typescript and ts-node installed as devDependencies. WebdriverIO will automatically detect if these dependencies are installed and will compile your config and tests for you. If you need to configure how ts-node runs please use the environment variables for ts-node or use wdio config's autoCompileOpts section.

Basically, it means that wdio automatically detects if you are using javascript or typescript.

But also it allows you to set specific configurations for typescript by setting an `autoCompileOpts` entry in your `wdio.conf.ts` file:

```
export const config = {
// ...
autoCompileOpts: {
    autoCompile: true,
    // see https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#cli-and-programmatic-options
    // for all available options
    tsNodeOpts: {
        transpileOnly: true,
        project: 'tsconfig.json'
    },
    // tsconfig-paths is only used if "tsConfigPathsOpts" are provided, if you
    // do please make sure "tsconfig-paths" is installed as dependency
    tsConfigPathsOpts: {
        baseUrl: './'
    }
}
```

}

Hope it helps to clarify your doubt!